# In eclipse, is it possible to change what the default package is without changing the source folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I'm working with some people on a java project. Problem is, I'm the only one using eclipse. The source files are located in svn in trunk/src/*.java. However, if I import that as a project directory, the default package is "" instead of what the actual project package name is.

Is there a way to change that without changing the source location and the package name?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused; why are starting your Eclipse project in `trunk` instead of the directory with `src` in it? In any case, you can set arbitrary directories as source directories in the project configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean that you want code in package `foo.bar` without having a matching directory folder of `foo/bar` under some source root - no, I don't *think* Eclipse supports that. While the convention of source locations having to match package structure isn't *enforced* by the language specification, it's mentioned there and so widely respected that I think it would be a bad idea to do anything else.

Comment: Some of the other people are using IntelliJ right now. Would moving the sources mess up the other's projects?

Comment: @Xzhsh: I don't know - I haven't used IntelliJ. But placing source in a conventional package structure is likely to be in the best interests of being able to use a wide variety of tools, even if it means short term breakage.

Comment: Be sure to do an `svn mv` rather than just moving the files using the built-in `mv` or whatever, otherwise you lose the history of those files (which is a good reason to switch to git, but I digress)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse requires a directory structure that matches the package structure. There is no option to have some package prefix that isn't reflected in directories.

IntelliJ can work with this, and it's what most people expect to see most of the time anway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are checking out the incorrect root folder.

If you are trying to work with a collection of source files located under `trunk/src/` you may be don't need to check out this folder, because you will loose your reference to the main package (for example `foo.bar`) because it will be the base package.

You may need to check out the `trunk/` folder, because Eclipse expects to find the source files under the default `/src` folder. Once you have your main root folder (with a lot of files like `.project`, `.classpath` inside), it is likely possible that Eclipse will recognize your folder structure and configuration and your project will compile without problems.